# Iterate through a list using re.sub()

Tags: python

I am trying to replace the valuse in a list with the long format name.

```
value_list = ['Gi1/0/8', 'Gi1/0/31', 'Gi1/0/32', 'Gi1/0/33', 'Gi1/0/34', 'Gi1/0/23', 'Gi1/0/27']
```

I am running the following script:

```
for value in value_list:
    value = re.sub(r'Gi', 'GigabitEthernet', value)
    print value
print value_list
```

This is my out put:

```
GigabitEthernet1/0/8
GigabitEthernet1/0/31
GigabitEthernet1/0/32
GigabitEthernet1/0/33
GigabitEthernet1/0/34
GigabitEthernet1/0/23
GigabitEthernet1/0/27
```

I just need to change the values in the list, it seems doing it all wrong. Can anyone help me do this in an efficient manner so i dont need to create another list from the individual outputs??

Answer (score 1):

Then use list comprehension instead:

```
print([re.sub(r'Gi', 'GigabitEthernet', value) for value in value_list])
```

Output:

```
['GigabitEthernet1/0/8', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/31', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/32', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/33', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/34', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/23', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/27']
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the list "in-place" you need to set each item in the list to the new value.  Just doing `value = re.sub(r'Gi', 'GigabitEthernet', item)` doesn't change the value stored in the list.

This code changes the values in the list:

```
>>> value_list = ['Gi1/0/8', 'Gi1/0/31', 'Gi1/0/32', 'Gi1/0/33', 'Gi1/0/34', 'Gi1/0/23', 'Gi1/0/27']

>>> for idx, item in enumerate(value_list):
...     value_list[idx] = re.sub(r'Gi', 'GigabitEthernet', item)
... 
>>> value_list
['GigabitEthernet1/0/8', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/31', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/32', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/33', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/34', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/23', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/27']
```

The [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate) function generates the list indexes for you, so you can iterate over your list pythonically (`for item in mylist`) rather than indexing directly (`for i in range(len(mylist))`) which produces less readable code.

Answer (score 1):

This code updates existing list:

```
value_list = ['Gi1/0/8', 'Gi1/0/31', 'Gi1/0/32', 'Gi1/0/33', 'Gi1/0/34', 'Gi1/0/23', 'Gi1/0/27']

for i in range(len(value_list)):
    value_list[i] = re.sub(r'Gi', 'GigabitEthernet', value_list[i])

print value_list
# ['GigabitEthernet1/0/8', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/31', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/32', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/33', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/34', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/23', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/27']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

**Ex:**

```
import re

value_list = ['Gi1/0/8', 'Gi1/0/31', 'Gi1/0/32', 'Gi1/0/33', 'Gi1/0/34', 'Gi1/0/23', 'Gi1/0/27']
value_list = list(map(lambda value: re.sub(r'Gi', 'GigabitEthernet', value), value_list))
print(value_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['GigabitEthernet1/0/8', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/31', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/32', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/33', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/34', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/23', 'GigabitEthernet1/0/27']
```